# Get name of a Google group

Tags: google-apps-script, google-groups

Isn't there a possibility to get the name of a Google group?

At the moment, I use this code:

```
function myFunction() {
   var groups=["group1@company.com","group2@company.com"];
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   for (var a=0;a<groups.length;a++){
      var group = GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail(groups[a]);
      var users = group.getUsers();
      sheet.getRange(1,a+1).setValue(groups[a]);
      sheet.getRange(1,a+1).setFontSize(12)
      for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
         var user = users[i];
         sheet.getRange(i+2,a+1).setValue(user.getEmail());
      }
   }
}
```

This code is working perfectly and writes the email of the group in the header row.
But I need something like "group.getName()" to write the NAME of the group in the header row.

Franz

Comment: Feature requests should be reported via the [Google Apps Script Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/).

Comment: Mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `GroupsApp` will not give you this. `AdminGroupsSettings` is what your are looking for. You will be able to get more information like description as well. Your new code will look like this.

```
function myFunction() {
   var groups=["group1@company.com","group2@company.com"];
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   for (var a=0;a<groups.length;a++){
      var group = GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail(groups[a]);
      var users = group.getUsers();
      sheet.getRange(1,a+1).setValue(AdminGroupsSettings.Groups.get(groups[a]).name);
      sheet.getRange(1,a+1).setFontSize(12)
      for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
         var user = users[i];
         sheet.getRange(i+2,a+1).setValue(user.getEmail());
      }
   }
}
```

Ofcourse, for this to work:

1. Enable `Groups Settings API` in `Advanced Google Services` under `Resources`.
2. Click on the `Google Developers Console` link in the popup and enable `Groups Settings API` in the console there.

I checked, this works.